# Unable to locate package chromium-chromedriver

Tags: docker

I am using this Dockerfile to build my package:

```
FROM python:3.9

MAINTAINER jiangxiaoqiang (example@gmail.com)

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && mkdir -p /root/pydolphin \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install ffmpeg chromium-chromedriver libsm6 libxext6 vim -y


ADD dolphin /root/pydolphin/dolphin
ADD requirements-pip.txt /root/pydolphin/
ADD schedulespider.py /root/pydolphin/
ADD docker-start-app.sh /root/pydolphin/
ADD cert_check_trigger.py /root/pydolphin/

RUN pip3 install -r /root/pydolphin/requirements-pip.txt
WORKDIR /root/pydolphin/
ENTRYPOINT exec /root/pydolphin/docker-start-app.sh
```

but shows this error:

```
Unable to locate package chromium-chromedriver
```

what should I do to make it could install `chromium-chromedriver`?

Comment: To be able to install `chromium-chromedriver` you would need to use ubuntu(-based) image, not debian(-based).

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, in debian I see there is a [chromium-driver](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/chromium-driver), you want to try that one.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @jabbson , you need to install [chromium-driver](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/chromium-driver)

The official Python Docker image is based on Debian ([reference](https://hub.docker.com/_/python)), while chromium-chromedriver is a Ubuntu package. They both fulfill the same need (Browser automation)